# ng-focus or ng-click is not working in Angular as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a text input field and a datepicker embedded in it. The problem is when we focus or even click on the input field

the date picker does not get showed.

But if you put a debugger and debug in console , it shows when the input field gets focused or clicked.

```
   <div class="row">
                <input id="field" placeholder="Choose Date" class="span-12" ng-model="vm.date" ng-blur="vm.onSaveTime()" ng-focus="vm.showDatePicker()">
   </div>
```

Here is the code

```
vm.showDatePicker = function(){
    debugger;
    var options = {
        format:"YYYY-MM-DD"
    };
    $('#field').datepicker(options);
}
```

**The date picker does not show initially when the page loads and if you don't debug in console or if you do not click other fields in the panel and then after click on it .**

Why is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be help you

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-app="myApp">
<p>{{datePicker || "00/00/0000"}}</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="datePicker" datepicker />
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive("datepicker", function () {
return {
restrict: "A",
require: "ngModel",
link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
  var updateModel = function (dateText) {
    scope.$apply(function () {
      ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
    });
  };
  var options = {
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onSelect: function (dateText) {
      updateModel(dateText);
    }
  };
  elem.datepicker(options);
}
}
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWeWVp